# Get value from database into div according to x-editable element (I'm using Flask)

Tags: javascript, python, flask, x-editable

I want to get a value from a database into a div according to an x-editable.

[image]

So for example if I edit CODE, it will update ITEM according to the value "151001".

If the database if something like this:

```
code   description
151001 "Item 1"
```

It will show "Item 1" in the ITEM

The most close example I've come across to this problem is this fiddle, but it does not include the database part: http://jsfiddle.net/neAWw/2/

I'm learning flask, and know a little html and javascript. Just the basic to do a simple web page. But I don't know where to start to acomplish this. Do I need to learn jquery, ajax? Can someone give me some advice how to start or maybe an example?